# Make all campaigns in Opporunities' - campaign influence related list as PRIMARY CAMPAIGN SOURCE

Tags: controller, campaign, trigger, campaign-influence

As shown in the below picture, Opportunity - 'Ethan Hunter' has two campaigns under campaign influence related list. In that Chat Campaign is marked as Primary Campaign Source. I would like to have the other campaign - IBTUF checked as Primary Campaign Source too.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not doable but the good news is that a feature to manipulate `Campaign Influence` looks imminent. See (and vote up) Idea [Make 'Campaign Influence' accessible via API / Apex / Visualforce](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000006n77AAA)

> We're looking at a pilot for this feature (safe harbor - Summer '16 or
>   Winter '17). Please contact me if you might be interested in the pilot
>   or providing your requirements for this feature
>   (meredith.brown@salesforce.com)

*I see no mention of this though in the Summer 16 release notes.*

Answer (score 0):

Its in the documentation that only one campaign can be primary for an Opportunity. See [Adding Influential Campaigns to Opportunities](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=campaigns_influence_using.htm).

> Though multiple campaigns can be influential, you can designate only one campaign as the primary campaign source on the opportunity.